# dropdown menu not appearing when hovered

Tags: html, css

Im trying to figure out why my dropdown menu on the right insnt working when hovered. Its probably something really simply that I've missed and I'm obviously missing it! .vanish:hover .dropdown doesnt seem to be hitting the spot...What am I doing wrong?

https://plnkr.co/edit/Cnh6G1cGE1v4zCnuftgy?p=preview

```
.vanish:hover .dropdown {
   display: flex;
   flex-direction: column;
   position: absolute;
   left: -10px;
   top: -10px;
   background-color: #dcf1f2;
   border-radius: 10px;
}
```

Comment: @Paulie_D Did you actually click the link? it's a link to a snippet example... it isnt a personal web page.

Comment: Code has to be **in the question**. A link to an *example* isn't enough

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to move the `ul.dropdown` under your `li`:

```
<li class="vanish">
  <span>Account</span>
  <ul class="dropdown">
    <li><a href="#">Login</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Sign Up</a></li>
  </ul>
</li>
```

Once I did that, on hover it was properly showing the dropdown.  (also you had an extra `li` tag)

Plunker: https://next.plnkr.co/edit/leakntv0F7pMpnWL

Comment: amazing!...i must have checked the code about 100 times and never once noticed the extra closing li at the end of that. Thank you

Comment: @rickwall glad I could help!!  Would you mind marking this as the answer to help me out with that reputation now? ;)